# Do something on each property change

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

I have several properties in my class, I would like to call `saveToFile` on each property change.

I prefer not to override the setter of each property.  Should I override
`-[NSObject methodForSelector]`? What is the best way to go?

Comment: Please provide some code as a sample. Is this for Objective-C? Please mark so in the tags.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can register as observer to the properties you want monitored. [Cocoa's KVO](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) functionality will help you here.

Basically you need to call `addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:` and register to be notified when the properties change. When this happens, the runtime calls the `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` method on the object registered as observer. You can do here the saving you want  to do.

Example for registering:

```
for(NSString *propName in self.propsIWantMonitored) {
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:propName change:0 context:@selector(saveToFile)];
}
```

and for dealing with the change of the prop values:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{

    // make sure we don't interfere with other observed props
    // and check the context param
    if (context == @selector(saveToFile)) {
        [self saveToFile];
    }
}
```

and for de-registering:

```
for(NSString *propName in self.propsIWantMonitored) {
    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:propName context:@selector(saveToFile)];
}
```

The code samples above assume you have declared an array of properties to monitor, that you use to register as observer to. You use the `context` parameter to determine if `observeValueForKeyPath` was called as a response to the observer you just registered, or not, in order not to get into conflict with other KVO registrations made from other parts of your class.

---

#### Alternative (and more energy efficient) approach to your problem

There's one caveat with the above approach: if multiple properties are set consecutively, then the `saveToFile` method will be called multiple times in a short period of time, which might cause performance bottlenecks and increase the energy usage of your application.

An alternative approach would be to have a `dirty` flag that gets set in `observeValueForKeyPath:` and gets reset in `saveToFile`. And you can have `saveToFile` check the flag and don't go use the file system if the object is not dirty.

You can schedule a timer that will periodically call `saveToFile`, this way multiple properties set at once will result in only one disk access. You can always manually call `saveToFile` when you feel want an immediate save.

Note. By timer I was referring to a [GCD timer](https://gist.github.com/maicki/7622108), as NSTimer also has a negative energy impact on your application.

Answer (score 5):

What you want is called Key-Value-Observing or KVO.
You register for example a method that gets called every time the property changes.

If you have a text field and you want to listen to changes to its text, you would register like this

```
[self.textField addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"text" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

And in your class you would implement this method:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{

    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"text"]) {

        NSLog(@"Textfield changed - MAKE CHANGES HERE");
    }

}
```

Here's a nice tutorial, if you aren't familiar with KVO:
http://www.appcoda.com/understanding-key-value-observing-coding/

Answer (score -3):

Read up on Property Observers. An example in Swift:

```
var currentSession: Session? {
    didSet {
        if let session = self.currentSession {
            // Write session to file.
        }
    }
}
```

For Objective-C, [key-value observing](http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/) might be more proper.